# set global variable to value of clicked item angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to assign a global variable `$rootScope.pageClass` with the value of the item clicked in the ng-repeat loop, but not sure if this is correct.

**Controller**

```
.controller('teamController', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.team = [];

    $scope.setTeamClass = function(teamname) {  
$rootScope.pageClass = teamname;
}


<tr ng-repeat="team in teamsList.standing">
        <td>
            <a ng-click="setTeamClass( {{teamName(team.teamName)}} )" href="#/teams/{{teamID(team._links.team.href)}}">
              {{teamName(team.teamName)}}
            </a>
```

It it gives me this error:

```
invalid key at column 16 of the expression [setTeamClass( {{team.teamName}} )] starting at [{team.teamName}}
```

Comment: What is teamName(team.teamName)? i dont see that function. setTeamClass(team.teamName) maybe?

Comment: doesn't work no not sure why not

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use {{}} for passing parameters to the function. Try this 
ng-click="setTeamClass( team.teamName )"